# Execute native plugin from ChildBrowser

Tags: cordova

From Child browser window i am trying to execute cordova ios native plugin. But its not working. Will Childbrowser supports to exec any phonegap native plugin?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not support the plugin API . Think of the child browser as a sandbox where you can view web pages but they can't get access to the apps info or device Apis.

Comment: Hi Simon, is there any other work around to execute cordova plugin? I want to extract zip file using plugin for button click inside the child browser page.

Comment: No, that would be a horrible idea. Then any remote page could execute code that accesses the device. To do what you want you should load the page into the main app and whitelist the remote web page.